# 'rand': no implicit conversion of range into integer

Tags: ruby

This is the code:

```
#this is the array that the numbers are stored on and where x is created
@numbers =    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90]

#getting the lowest number and taking away 1 so it matches the number at the appropiate index in the array
def get_low()
    number1 = $stdin.gets.chomp
    new1 = number1.to_i - 1
end

#getting the highest number and taking away 1 so it matches the number at the appropiate index in the array
def get_high()
    number2 = $stdin.gets.chomp
    new2 = number2.to_i - 1
end


#these lines ask the user for the highest and lowest possible number, and call the functions needed to create the 10 random numbers
print "\nNote: limit is between 1 and 90"
print "\nLowest possible number is.... "
puts get_low()
print "\nHighest possible number is.... "
puts get_high()
print "\nYour 10 random numbers are now being generated..."
print  "\nYour numbers are: "
print "\n"

#using the rand() function to get 10 random numbers between get_low and get_high
def get_numbers()
    x = "\"#{@numbers[rand("#{get_low}".."#{get_high}")]}\" , \n \"#{@numbers[rand("#{get_low}".."#{get_high}")]}\" , \n\"#{@numbers[rand("#{get_low}".."#{get_high}")]}\" , \n\"#{@numbers[rand("#{get_low}".."#{get_high}")]}\" , \n \"#{@numbers[rand("#{get_low}".."#{get_high}")]}\" , \n\"#{@numbers[rand("#{get_low}".."#{get_high}")]}\" , \n\"#{@numbers[rand("#{get_low}".."#{get_high}")]}\" , \n\"#{@numbers[rand("#{get_low}".."#{get_high}")]}\" , \n\"#{@numbers[rand("#{get_low}".."#{get_high}")]}\" , \n\"#{@numbers[rand("#{get_low}".."#{get_high}")]}\" "
end


puts get_numbers()
```

but when i run it, I get the following error about line 29:

```
in 'rand': no implicit conversion of range into integer (TypeError)
from C:/ruby/ca.rb:29:in 'get_numbers'
from C:/ruby/ca.rb:33:in '<main>'
```

Comment: Add your code to the question, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know: `rand(1..90)` will give you a random number between 1 and 90.

Comment: yes but i need to assign it to something so i can print all the random numbers later

Comment: @numbers = [*(1..90)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, the code you have written can be improved many ways. I wish to share another way to look at the problem, have a look and see if you are able to understand it:

```
module Config
  NUMBER_OF_RANDOM_NUMBERS_PER_GAME = 10
  NUMBER_OF_GAMES = 5
end

class RandomTen
  def initialize
    user_input
  end

  def array
    Config::NUMBER_OF_RANDOM_NUMBERS_PER_GAME.times.map { rand range }
  end

  private

  def user_input
    puts
    puts "Random number range"
    print "Low : "
    @low = gets.chomp.to_i
    print "High: "
    @high = gets.chomp.to_i
  end

  def range
    @low..@high
  end
end

class Game
  def self.play
    Game.new.run.print
  end

  def run
    @results = collect_games do
      RandomTen.new.array.sort
    end

    self
  end

  def print
    puts
    puts "Sorted random arrays: "
    @results.each_with_index do |result, index|
      puts "Game #{index + 1} : #{result}"
    end
  end

  private

  def collect_games(&block)
    Config::NUMBER_OF_GAMES.times.map(&block)
  end
end

Game.play

# ruby game.rb =>
#
# Random number range
# Low : 2
# High: 9
#
# Random number range
# Low : 1
# High: 6
#
# Random number range
# Low : 2
# High: 7
#
# Random number range
# Low : 3
# High: 7
#
# Random number range
# Low : 3
# High: 8
#
# Sorted random arrays:
# Game 1 : [2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9]
# Game 2 : [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
# Game 3 : [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]
# Game 4 : [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7]
# Game 5 : [3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

Note:

- I avoided limiting the limits for the random numbers as I believe you may have done that because of the way you created the array.

Comment: it worked :) but has a new array been stored...and if so what? I need all numbers to be stored so when they have finished all the numbers can be sorted and printed

Comment: I didn't quite get what your requirement is? You mean you want to write the array into a file?

Comment: in other words, can I store all random numbers in another array, so when the user decides to, they can view all the random numbers over the course of say...5 goes. Can these numbers then be sorted?

Comment: Take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have access to ruby interpreter at the moment)

It fails probably because you pass range of Strings to rand method, but you should pass range of integers. Remove " from ranges and it should work

Comment: do you mean by removing the \" before each # and after the closing }'s. Because I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: I mean this `@numbers[rand(#{get_low}..#{get_high})]` instead of `@numbers[rand("#{get_low}".."#{get_high}")]`

Comment: now it comes up with @numbers[rand(-1..-1)]

Comment: as I understand -1 is returned from get_high/get_low methods. They should return values greater than 0...

Comment: @Fin it works, it doesn't work?

Comment: it doesn't work as i it now says @numers[rand(..)] as i added 0 to the array, and took out new1 and new2, and changed x= to ="@numbers[rand(#{get_low}..#{get_high})]"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a random number between the input low and the input high.  I'd try get_low plus rand( get_high ).

The problem reported is that this rand function wants an int, and you're currently passing a range ( a.. b).

Comment: I did this:    x ="@numbers[#{get_low} + rand(#{get_high})]" and it came up with : @numbers[-1 + rand(-1)] instead of 10 random numbers

Comment: Did you input zeros for the low and high?  With the code subtracting 1, that would explain the -1's.  And how about removing the double quotes?

Comment: i did that and it came up with the error about line 27 in 'rand':no implicit conversion of string to integer

Comment: line 27:x =@numbers["#{get_low}" + rand("#{get_high}")]